# Bash script: using variables / parameter in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a little bash script, where you can specify a number of minutes and it will show the lines of a log file from those last X minutes.
To get the lines, I am using sed

```
sed -n '/time/,/time/p' LOGFILE
```

On CLI this works perfectly, in my script however, it does not.

```
# Get date
now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T")

# Get date minus X number of minutes -- $1 first argument, minutes
then=$(date -d "-$1 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %T")

# Filter logs -- $2 second argument, filename
sed -n '/'$then'/,/'$now'/p' $2
```

I have tried different approaches and none of them seem to work:

```
result=$(sed -n '/"$then"/,/"$now"/p' $2)
sed -n "/'$then'/,/'$now'/p" "$2"
sed -n "/$then/,/$now/p" $2
sed -n "/$then/,/$now/p" "$2
```

Any sugesstions?
I am on Debian 5, `echo $SHELL` says `/bin/sh`

**EDIT :** The script produces no output, so there is no error showing up.
In the logfile every entry starts with a date like this `2013-05-15 14:21:42,794`

Comment: Can you show a line from the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the main problem is that you try to perform an arithmetic comparison by string matching. `sed -n '/23/,/27/p'` gives you the lines between the first line that contains `23` and the next line that contains `27` (and then again from the next line that contains `23` to the next line that contains `27`, and so on). It does **not** give you all lines that contain a number between 23 and 27. If the input looks like

```
19
22
24
26
27
30
```

it does not output anything (since there is no `23`). An awk solution that uses string matching has the same problem. So, unless your `then` date string occurs verbatim in the log file, your method will fail. You have to convert your date strings into numbers (drop the `-`, `<space>`, and `:`) and then check whether the resulting number is in the right range, using an arithmetical comparison rather than a string match. This goes beyond the capabilities of sed; awk and perl can do it rather easily. Here is a perl solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
THEN=$(date -d "-$1 minutes" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

perl -wne '
  if (m/^(....)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..)/) {
    $date = "$1$2$3$4$5$6";
    if ($date >= '"$THEN"' && $date <= '"$NOW"') {
      print;
    }
  }' "$2"
```

Comment: Allright, this works. It's a pitty that it doesn't work out the box with shell tools

Comment: You could also use `sed -e 's/^\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\) \(..\):\(..\):\(..\)/\1\2\3\4\5\6 /' "$2" | awk '$1 >= '"$THEN"' && $1 <= '"$NOW" | sed -e 's/^\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\) /\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'`, if you prefer a traditional shell pipeline, but that's not really more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give yourself a headache with nested quotes. Use the `-v` option with `awk` to pass the value of a shell variable into the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get date
now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T")

# Get date minus X number of minutes -- $1 first argument, minutes
delta=$(date -d "-$1 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %T")

# Filter logs -- $2 second argument, filename
awk -v n="$now" -v d="$delta" '$0~n,$0~d' $2
```

Also don't use variable names of shell builtins i.e `then`.

Comment: I have fixed the little typo (`-v`instead of `=v`), unfortunately, this produces no output either.

Comment: good spot. Try debugging the problem then, add `echo "$now $delta"` in script and check the formats match the format in your log file.

Comment: Well, that was the right hint. Since I am olny checkcing for HH:MM:SS and the logs are HH:MM:SS,MS, the script didn't find anything. I adjusted my script to `sed -n "/$then*/,/$now*/p" $2`. I am not sure, how to adapt the awk command properly but once adapted, it should work, too.

Comment: `HH:MM:SS` is a substring of `HH:MM:SS,MS` so that doesn't explain it?

Comment: hmm...you are right, it's not working...eventhough it did once. Like I wrote in my first post, the log format is `2013-05-15 14:21:42,794` followed by a whitespace and then the logging information, the scripts format is `2013-05-15 14:21:42`.